# How to change the color of a single line on mousePress()

Tags: java, processing

I have this small piece of code for a prototype.

I'm trying to have it so that on mousePressed() or on mouseClicked() the colour of the line clicked on will change.

I can't for the life of me figure it out!

Any help would be much appreciated!

The code I have so far managed to write is below, it should work fine.

```java
int value = 0;
ArrayList<Line> l = new ArrayList<Line>();

void setup() {
   size(500,500);
   background(57, 76, 222);
   //noLoop();
   stroke(255);
   strokeWeight(3);
}

void draw() {
    for (int i = 1; i< 20; i++) {
        l.add(new Line());   
        for (int a=0; a< l.size(); a++){
            l.get(a).display();
            noLoop();
        }
    }
    int total = l.size();
    println("The total number of lines is: " + total);
}


class Line {
    int ranX1, ranX2, ranY1, ranY2;

    Line() {
        ranX1 = int(random(50,450));
        ranX2 = int(random(50,450));
        ranY1 = int(random(50,450));
        ranY2 = int(random(50,450));
    }

    void update() {
        //
    }

    void display() {
        line(ranX1,ranX2,ranY1,ranY2);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I were you I'd start by googling "point line segment collision detection" or "detect if point is near line segment" or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a line, given by a point (`O`) and an direction (`D`), then the nearest point on the line, to a point p can be calculated as follows

```
X = O + D * dot(P-O, D);
```

[image]

The dot product of 2 vectors is equal the cosine of the angle between the 2 vectors multiplied by the magnitude (length) of both vectors.

[image]

```
dot( A, B ) == | A | * | B | * cos( alpha )
```

The dot product of `V` and `D` is equal the cosine of the angle between the line (`O`, `D`) and the vector `V = P - O`, multiplied by the amount (length) of `V`, because `D` is a [unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) (the lenght of `D` is 1.0).

Use [`PVector`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector.html) to get the direction from (`ranX1`, `ranY1`) to (`ranX2`, `ranY2`) and make the direction vector to an unit vector by [`.normalize()`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_normalize_.html). The length of the vector is verified by [`.mag()`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_mag_.html):

```java
PVector D = new PVector(ranX2 - ranX1, ranY2 - ranY1);
if ( D.mag() > 0.0 )
    D.normalize();
```

Use the above algorithm to calculate the normal distance to an endless line, where0 the points (`ranX1`, `ranY1`) and (`ranX2`, `ranY2`) are on. For this the methods [`.mult()`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_mult_.html), [`.add()`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_add_.html), [`.dist()`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_dist_.html) and [`.dot()`](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_dot_.html) are used:

```java
PVector X = new PVector(ranX1, ranY1);
X.add( D.mult( D.dot( vP1 ) ) );
boolean hit = X.dist(new PVector(x, y)) < hit_dist;
```

Use the dot product to verify if the intersection point (`X`) of the line and the normal line through the an point (`x`, `y`) is in between (`ranX1`, `ranY1`) and (`ranX2`, `ranY2`). The dot product is less than 0.0 if the angle between two linens is greater 90 degrees or less than -90 degrees:

```java
PVector vP1 = new PVector(x - ranX1, y - ranY1);
if ( D.dot( vP1 ) < 0.0 )
    hit = false;

PVector vP2 = new PVector(x - ranX2, y - ranY2);
if ( D.dot( vP2 ) > 0.0 )
    hit = false;
```

Add a method `isHit` to the class `Line`, which checks if an input position (`x`, `y`) is on the line. The acceptable accuracy to identify a click on the line can be set by `hit_dist`. Decrease this vaule if the line has to be hit exactly. Increase it to allow hit beside but near the line, too. Add an color attribute `col` and a method which can change the color:

```java
class Line {

    // [...]

    color col;

    // [...]

    void setColor(color c) {
        col = c;
    }

    boolean isHit(int x, int y) {

        final int hit_dist = 5;

        // [...]

        return hit;
    }
}
```

Use the mouse pressed event [`mousePressed()`](https://processing.org/reference/mousePressed_.html) to travers all the lines in a loop. Change the color of each line is 2hit" by the mouse when the mouse is pressed:

```java
void mousePressed() {

    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); ++i) {

        if (l.get(i).isHit(mouseX, mouseY)) {
            l.get(i).setColor(color(255, 0, 0) );
        }
    } 
}
```

See the example, which implements the algorithm and does some further improvements and bug fixes to your code:

[image]

```java
int value = 0;
ArrayList<Line> l = new ArrayList<Line>();

void setup() {
    size(500,500);

   for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
       l.add(new Line());  
   }
}

void draw() {

    background(57, 76, 222);

    strokeWeight(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); ++i) {
       l.get(i).display();
    }
}

void mousePressed() {

    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); ++i) {

        if (l.get(i).isHit(mouseX, mouseY)) {
            l.get(i).setColor(color(255, 0, 0) );
        }
    } 
}

class Line {
    int ranX1, ranX2, ranY1, ranY2;
    color col;

    Line() {
        col = color(255);
        ranX1 = int(random(50,450));
        ranX2 = int(random(50,450));
        ranY1 = int(random(50,450));
        ranY2 = int(random(50,450));
    }

    void setColor(color c) {
        col = c;
    }

    boolean isHit(int x, int y) {

        final int hit_dist = 5;

        PVector D = new PVector(ranX2 - ranX1, ranY2 - ranY1);
        if ( D.mag() > 0.0 )
            D.normalize();

        PVector vP1 = new PVector(x - ranX1, y - ranY1);
        if ( D.dot( vP1 ) < 0.0 )
            return false;

        PVector vP2 = new PVector(x - ranX2, y - ranY2);
        if ( D.dot( vP2 ) > 0.0 )
            return false;

        PVector X = new PVector(ranX1, ranY1);
        X.add( D.mult( D.dot( vP1 ) ) );
        boolean hit = X.dist(new PVector(x, y)) < hit_dist; 

        return hit;
    }

    void display() {
        stroke(col);
        line(ranX1, ranY1, ranX2, ranY2);
    }
}
```